# Where can I find a list of credit card interest rates for US issuers?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, interest-rate

I'm looking for a website (hopefully *independent* of major card issuers) that has a good list and comparisons of credit card interest rates for the United States as well as historical data showing how often they change (raise) their rates.

Comment: What country? In the US the credit rates are set based on the card holder history, same card can have different rates for different people. You can see the possible ranges in the disclosures.

Comment: @littleadv updated with country.

Comment: How does it matter, unless you are doing some kind of reporting on the credit industry? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Many places. I usually look at these two:

[CreditCards.com](http://www.creditcards.com/) and [BankRate.com](http://www.bankrate.com/credit-cards.aspx). They conduct surveys and you can find some historical information, but let me reiterate: the rates are set and changed per card-holder based on the card-holder's history. Also, because of the [CARD Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009) changes, the historical trends and patterns will not necessarily be relevant any more. The new law limits the rates and how they can be changed, and the historical data does not reflect the new rules.